# Inform preferred choice about another offer

Tags: job-offer, internship

I've applied to two schools for a school psych internship and I've just gotten an offer from my 2nd choice and they said they need a response by next Wednesday. However, my preferred choice told me that they likely wouldn't get back to me until after next week because of spring break. How can I inform my preferred choice about the other offer without sounding pushy?

Comment: Under what terms did the first choice tell you they wouldn't get back until after next week? It sounds like you may have already asked them for a date?

Comment: just tell them as you've told us, only ask if you can have an expedited response. nothing pushy about it. you can also agree to the second choice and then withdraw if you get the first choice.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, tell them you've applied to multiple and won't hear back from the rest so it would be difficult to make their decision.  Then they will tell you, too bad let us know by Wednesday, or OK let us know by another date.